# Force cursor override for page

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a DevExtreme React component. It has the ability to drag and drop.

My task is to change the cursor. It is not possible to do this through the library mechanisms. Is it possible to somehow force the cursor to change for the entire page on a dragging event?

I already tried to replace the cursor directly using:

```
document.body.style.cursor = 'copy';
```

but this does not help since there are apparently overrides inside the component.